# Android - Where to place app's general information / imprint / contact info / about?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-preferences

I want to have an Imprint in my app with information such as the app's version number, its logo, an email address, etc. but I'm not sure where should it be placed and how.

In the [design Help docs from Android](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/help.html) seems like the right place is there, in the "Help" section of the action overflow but in most of the apps that I have, this kind of information usually falls into the "Settings" section. In my case, I won't have a Help section, so I thought about having my Imprint in the Settings, but then, how do I implement it? It seems to me that the Settings are meant to... yeah, change the behavior of the app and therefore all the classes of the Preference package (CheckBoxPreference, SwitchPreference, etc.) go on that direction and are not meant to just present information. Should I use something like a DialogPreference, for example or there are better ways of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it seems normal to use one entry on the Settings screen for your "about" information, as some Google apps do this as well (Maps, Play Store, etc).

You can assign an Intent to a preference: see [setIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#setIntent%28android.content.Intent%29) on the documentation. It will be started when the preference is clicked.

So on your `onCreate` of the preference activity, you can do something similar to:

```
findPreference("your_preference_id").setIntent(new Intent(this, AboutActivity.class));
```